# How to test whether timezone exists in Python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, timezone, utc

I am working with pandas' `tz_localize` function to convert dates from local time to UTC:

```
time_zone = 'America/Santiago'    
pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime(df['mydate']).apply(lambda x: datetime.strftime(x, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'))).dt.tz_localize(time_zone).dt.tz_convert('UTC').dt.tz_localize(None)
```

This works well, but now I would like to check whether the user-defined `time_zone` actually exists prior to passing it into `tz_localize`. I found [lists of available countries](https://gist.github.com/heyalexej/8bf688fd67d7199be4a1682b3eec7568) online, but I do not know how to access this information directly in Python.

I have seen [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) about zoneinfo but I am looking for a Python/pandas alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the standard library's [`zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) and [`tzdata`](https://pypi.org/project/tzdata/):

```
# pip install tzdata  # already shipping with pandas
import zoneinfo

all_tz = zoneinfo.available_timezones()

if time_zone in all_tz:
    # your code
```

Alternatively, with [`pytz`](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) (now deprecated):

```
import pytz

if time_zone in pytz.all_timezones_set:
    # your code
```

If you have python <3.9, you can mimic the `zoneinfo.available_timezones` function with:

```
from importlib import resources

with resources.files('tzdata').joinpath('zones').open('r') as f:
    all_tz = set(x.strip('\n') for x in f.readlines())

if time_zone in all_tz:
    # your code
```

Comment: @FObersteiner there's actually also a standard library option for that (returns a set)

Comment: was about to comment that; should make sure then that `tzdata` is installed. might be a dependency of pandas already.

Comment: addendum: tzdata should be installed with pandas already; https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/requirements-dev.txt / https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pyproject.toml

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @mozway. If I understand the above comments properly, there is no way of listing the available time zones without installing either pytz or zoneinfo, although pandas seems to have access this information "internally", is that right?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @FObersteiner, but I am unsure how to access `tzdata`. Apparently I need to manually install zoneinfo first as running `from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo` returns a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: @Sheldon which python version do you use? `zoneinfo` shipped in python 3.9.

Comment: @Sheldon to clarify, you do not have to access tzdata directly, you just need it in the "background" on some systems to work with the zoneinfo module. tzdata automatically comes installed with pandas for instance.

Comment: I'm adding an alternative if you don't have `zoneinfo`

Comment: Thanks you for your thorough answer @mozway.